# UV unwrap results in non-desired size proportions

Tags: uv

I have a low poly face mesh with ears, face and cleavage.

I have marked the seam at the back of the neck (skull potion is non existent due to hair that covers it)

When blender unwraps it, a very large portion of the resulting UV island is dedicated to the cleavage because it has a bigger area. However I would like to have the actual face the "priority" for the unwrap.

Is it possible to do it automatically?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no automatic way of doing it, but you can enable proportional editing with sharp falloff, select a point in the center of the area you want to favour and scale the UV, maybe repeating the scaling operation a couple of times with different areas of influence.

[image]